# C#/F# interoperability: cannot use C# types in F# code

Tags: c#, f#, language-interoperability

I have a Visual Studio solution with 3 projects named BaseCs, UseCs and UseFs (all .net core 3.1 libraries).

- BaseCs is in C# and has only one source file Definitions.cs containing a series of type definitions
- UseCs is in C# has only one source file Use.cs containing a simple class with a method, creating    instances of types from BaseCs
- UseFs is the F# version of UseCs

```
//Definitions.cs
using System;

namespace BaseCs
{
    public interface IIdentity
    {
        string Value { get; }

        Guid GetGuid();
    }

    public abstract class Identity<T> : IIdentity where T : Identity<T>
    {
        public string Value { get; }

        public Guid GetGuid()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class EntityId : Identity<EntityId> { }

    public interface IMessage
    {
        string SourceId { get; }
    }

    public interface IAggregateEvent : IMessage { }

    public interface IAggregateEvent<out TIdentity> : IAggregateEvent
        where TIdentity : IIdentity
    {
        TIdentity Id { get; }
    }

    public interface IAggregateEvent<out TIdentity, out TData> : IAggregateEvent<TIdentity>
        where TIdentity : IIdentity
    {
        TData Data { get; }
    }


    public abstract class AggregateEvent<TIdentity, TData> : IAggregateEvent<TIdentity, TData> where TIdentity : IIdentity
    {
        protected AggregateEvent(TIdentity id, TData data, string sourceId)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Data = data;
            this.SourceId = sourceId;
        }

        public TData Data { get; }
        public TIdentity Id { get; }
        public string SourceId { get; }
    }

    public interface IAuditedAggregateEvent : IAggregateEvent
    {
        EntityId EntityId { get; set; }

        string EntitySortName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IAuditedAggregateEvent<out TIdentity, out TData> : IAuditedAggregateEvent, IAggregateEvent<TIdentity, TData>
        where TIdentity : IIdentity
    {
    }

    public abstract class AuditedAggregateEvent<TIdentity, TData> : AggregateEvent<TIdentity, TData>, IAuditedAggregateEvent<TIdentity, TData> where TIdentity : IIdentity
    {
        public AuditedAggregateEvent(TIdentity id, TData data, string sourceId) : base(id, data, sourceId)
        { }

        public EntityId EntityId { get; set; }
        public string EntitySortName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ISimpleAudit
    {
        EntityId CreatedBy { get; set; }
        string CreatedBySortName { get; set; }
        DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
        EntityId UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        string UpdatedBySortName { get; set; }
        DateTimeOffset UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class EntityData : ICloneable, ISimpleAudit
    {
        public object Clone()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public EntityId CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBySortName { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public EntityId UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBySortName { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IProtocol { }

    public interface IAccountingServiceProtocol : IProtocol { }

    public interface IEntityProtocol : IProtocol, IAccountingServiceProtocol { }

    public interface IDataImportEvent
    {
    }

    public interface IUnorderedEvent { }

    public class EntityImported : AuditedAggregateEvent<EntityId, EntityData>, IEntityProtocol, IDataImportEvent, IUnorderedEvent
    {
        public EntityImported(EntityId id, EntityData data, string sourceId) : base(id, data, sourceId) { }
    }
    public interface ICommandId
    {
        Guid CommandId { get; }
    }

    public interface ICommand : IMessage, ICommandId
    { }
    public interface IImportProtocol { }

    public class ImportEvent : ICommand, IImportProtocol
    {
        public ImportEvent(IAggregateEvent<IIdentity> @event, string sourceId)
        {
            Event = @event;
            SourceId = sourceId;
        }

        public static ImportEvent Of(IAggregateEvent<IIdentity> evt, string sourceId = null) => new ImportEvent(evt, sourceId);
        public string SourceId { get; }
        public Guid CommandId { get; }
        public IAggregateEvent<IIdentity> Event { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

```
//UseCs.cs
using BaseCs;
using System;

namespace UseCs
{
    public class UseCs
    {
        void method()
        {
            var entityImported = new EntityImported(null, null, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            var importEvent = new ImportEvent(entityImported, null);
        }
    }
}
```

```
//UseFs.fs
namespace UseFs

open BaseCs
open System

module UseFs =
    let method() =
        let entityImported = new EntityImported(null, null, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        let importEvent = new ImportEvent(entityImported, null); //compiler error: The type 'EntityImported' is not compatible with the type 'IAggregateEvent<IIdentity>'
        ()
```

No problem with Use.cs.
However, the F# compiler refuses to accept the code, complaining that **The type 'EntityImported' is not compatible with the type 'IAggregateEvent'**

[image]

**How do I get if F# UseFs.fs the same result as in C# UseCs.cs?**

Comment: You might need to explicitly cast it

Comment: @Foole Would you please give me a simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# does not support covariance/contravariance like C# does. There is an open issue about this [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/162).

Explicit (static) casting to `IAggregateEvent<IIdentity>` does not work in your case because of this.

All is not lost, however, since you can resort to dynamic upcast:

```
let importEvent = new ImportEvent(unbox entityImported, null)
```